# SET @xml = file_path

Tags: xml, database, import, sql-server-2008-r2

I need import an XML file into a SQL Server 2008 R2database.

So, I have query with hardcoded XML data:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml='
<goods_item>
<goods_level>1</goods_level>
<goods_isgroup>1</goods_isgroup>
<goods_code>51852</goods_code>
<goods_name></goods_name>
<goods_parent></goods_parent>
<goods_art></goods_art>
<goods_buhart></goods_buhart>
<goods_inpack>0</goods_inpack>
<goods_packtxt></goods_packtxt>
<goods_country></goods_country>
<goods_gtd></goods_gtd>
<goods_nds>0</goods_nds>
<goods_unit></goods_unit>
</goods_item>
<goods_item>
<goods_level>1</g    oods_level>
<goods_isgroup>1</goods_isgroup>
<goods_code>51852</goods_code>
<goods_name></goods_name>
<goods_parent></goods_parent>
<goods_art></goods_art>
<goods_buhart></goods_buhart>
<goods_inpack>0</goods_inpack>
<goods_packtxt></goods_packtxt>
<goods_country></goods_country>
<goods_gtd></goods_gtd>
<goods_nds>0</goods_nds>
<goods_unit></goods_unit>
</goods_item>'
```

And it works fine. But how can I change hardcode XML data to path to XML file?

Something about this:

```
SET @xml='D:\xml1.xml'
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like XML support are highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first import it into a temporary table like this:

```
declare @insert nvarchar(1000), @pathname varchar(200), @xml xml

set @pathname = 'your path here'

create table #tmp_xml(xmldata xml)

set @insert = 'INSERT INTO #tmp_xml(xmldata) SELECT bulkcolumn 
      FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N''' + @pathname+ ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS data'

exec sp_executesql @insert

select @xml = xmldata from #tmp_xml

-- read, parse xml here ....
drop table #tmp_xml
```